# Swift: static string evaluated empty

Tags: swift, static, null

I looked for this on SO and unfortunately there's no answer.

I have this declared:

```
struct ChatRoomsLite {
    public static let CHAT_ROOM_LITE_BASE = "ChatRoomsLite"
    public static let TIME_OF_LAST_MESSAGE = "timeLastMessage"
    public static let NUM_OF_UNREAD_MSGS = "unreadMessages"
    public static let LAST_MESSAGE = "lastMessage"
    public static let CONTACT_ID = "contactB_Id"
    public static let CONTACT_NAME = "contactName"
}
```

And for some reason, one of the constants is being evaluated EMPTY!

[image]

As you can see, the `CONTACT_NAME` is evaluated empty even though it's defined as `public static let`

How can this be fixed ?

Comment: Please do _not_ add code, error messages, etc as images - they're not searchable, and can't be copied when writing an answer.

Comment: Better now ? :)

Comment: Much better now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [The Swift Programming Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254) says:

> Global constants and variables are always computed lazily, in a similar manner to Lazy Stored Properties. Unlike [lazy stored properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID257), global constants and variables do not need to be marked with the lazy modifier.

So your constant is not empty, it simple hasn't been **instantiated** at that moment because you've never accessed it before.

Such behavior can not lead to any problem. Here is an example:

```
struct MyStruct {
    public static let ID = "Identifier"
}

//_ = MyStruct.ID

print(MyStruct.ID)
```

If you run this code and add a breakpoint at `print` line, you will also see that `MyStruct.ID` is empty, but correct value will be printed at the console, because constant was instantiated **after** first access.

If you uncomment the commented line and repeat the same thing, `MyStruct.ID` won't be empty at `print` line breakpoint, because it was already instantiated when you accessed it in a previous line.

Comment: Brilliant. So what you're saying is that it is empty atm because I stopped on a breakpoint but it will have a value once I step over ?

Comment: @Ofri Exactly. I've add an example to make it more clear.